# How to set auto height for Html text control in PowerApps?

Tags: powerapps

I have a screen in my PowerApps news browsing application which displays article title, it's title image, author name, date posted and it's html text. It looks like this:

[image]

I display html using [HTML text control](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/control-html-text/). It's height is fixed, and, when it has to display a long text, scroll bar appears but only for this control. So only half of the screen is scrollable. When I use usual [text box](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/control-text-box/) control I can set it's *'AutoHeight'* property to `true` and text box automatically increases it's [Height](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/properties-size-location/) property if it's [Text](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/properties-core/) property contains more characters than the control can show at one time. **How can I do something similar with *'HTML text control'*, make all the screen scrollable and show all of the html?**

Answer (score 0):

The `AutoHeight` property is not available in the [HTML Text control](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/control-html-text/). I'd suggest creating a new issue in the [PowerApps Ideas Board](https://aka.ms/powerapps-ideas) to make this suggestion to the product team.